# How many characters can a MySQL column with the size varchar(60) accomodate?

Tags: mysql, size, varchar

I have a column in a MySQL table that has the size of varchar(60). I need to create a text box in my webpage that can capture and store the text into this column. But before that I want to know how many actual characters can varchar(60) store. Thank you.

Comment: 60 actual characters.

Comment: What do you think the 60 means?

Comment: Is it actual 60 letters?

Comment: The 60 refers to _characters_, not _bytes_.